# How do I save data to my Ember store if the POST response contains only an id?

Tags: javascript, post, ember.js, ember-data

Ember data expects my server to return the full object after each successful `POST`. However, my API only returns a kind of meta-object that contains the `id`. When Ember receives this object, the existing data in the record gets deleted except for the `id`.

So for example, when I do this:

```
var asset = App.Asset.store.createRecord('asset',{name: 'foo.ai',
    paths: ['/path/foo.ai', '/another/path/foo.ai'],
    type: 'ai',
    hash: '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890',
    datecreated: 'Sun, 12 Jan 2014 06:01:48 GMT',
    datemodified: 'Sun, 12 Jan 2014 06:01:48 GMT',
    thumbnail: '/path/to/thumb.jpg'
});

asset.save();
```

... the server responds, like so:

```
{
    status: "OK",
    updated: "Mon, 13 Jan 2014 19:49:14 GMT",
    id: "52d4433a8e3b08444740ea47",
}
```

When Ember receives this, it updates the `id` of the record with what it received in the server response, but it also *deletes* all the other data because it wasn't in the response. If I examine my data in the Ember helper, it looks like this:

```
{   
    id: '52d4433a8e3b08444740ea47'
    name: undefined,
    paths: undefined,
    type: undefined,
    hash: undefined,
    datecreated: undefined,
    datemodified: undefined,
    thumbnail: undefined
}
```

**How can I override this behavior and get Ember to stop deleting my data?**

I've looked at:

- Hooking into `createRecord` in the `DS.RESTAdapter`, but it returns a promise, so I can't extract the new `id` yet.
- Hooking into `extractSave` in the `DS.RESTSerializer`, but it expects the `store`, `type`, and `payload` as inputs, not the individual `record`! If the record were passed into here, I could update its `id` with what's in the payload and solve my problem.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the existing data on the record is getting overwritten in the record's `adapterDidCommit` method.

See https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/model.js#L656-L657

One solution could be to extend that method to preserve existing data from the record. I believe it might look something like this.

```
DS.Model.reopen({
  adapterDidCommit: function() {
    var oldData = this.toJSON();
    this._super.apply(this, arguments); // calls the original adapterDidCommit method
    var newData = this._data;
    this._data = Ember.merge(oldData, newData);
  }
});
```

This code is probably not ideal because it modifies the `DS.Model` class but I didn't see a way to extend an adapter or serializer class to achieve a similar result.

Comment: Gorgeous! This worked perfectly. Meanwhile, I think that needing to modify DS.Model to get this to work is definitely in bug territory. There's an issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1438#issuecomment-33029855).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'm solving my problem at the moment with the following:

```
// Given a vanilla Javascript `data` object that contains your model data
var asset = App.Asset.store.createRecord('asset', data);
asset.save();

// The server response updated `asset` with an `id` but deleted everything
// else, so we copy the `id` to our `data` object and then update the store
data.id = asset.id;
App.Asset.store.update('asset', data);
```

This solution feels hacky and I'd much rather get it right the first time than do this little dance every time I need to save a record.